# How do I save an in memory Bitmap to a ZipArchive without saving the Bitmap to the file system first?

Tags: c#, file, bitmap, in-memory, c#-ziparchive

So I have some code that takes a capture of the screen and saves it to a jpeg file.  This works fine, however I want to instead save the jpeg encoded capture to a new ZipArchive without writing the Bitmap to the file system first.

Here is what I have so far:

```
FileInfo zipArchive = new FileInfo(fileToZip.FullName + ".zip");

using (ZipArchive zipFile = ZipFile.Open(zipArchive.FullName, ZipArchiveMode.Create)))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry zae = zipFile.CreateEntry(fileToZip.FullName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    using (Stream zipStream = zae.Open())
        bmp.Save(zipStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

The problem is that on the `bmp.Save()` line a `System.NotSupportedException` is thrown

> This stream from ZipArchiveEntry does not support seeking.

I've seen a lot of examples that write directly to the Stream returned from `zae.Open()` so I am not sure why this doesn't work because I figured that all `bmp.Save()` would need to do is write, not seek.  I don't know if this would work but I don't want to have to save the Bitmap to a `MemoryStream` and the copy that stream to the Stream returned from `zae.Open()` because it feels like unnecessary extra work.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many file formats have pointers to other parts of the file, or length values, which may not be known beforehand. The simplest way is to just write zeros first, then the data and then seek to change the value. If this way is used, there is no way to get by this, so you will need to first write the data into a `MemoryStream` and then write the resulting data into the `ZipStream`, as you mentioned.

This doesn't really add that much code and is a simple fix for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the in file pointers/ length and how that would add the seeking requirement, I hadn't thought of that.  I started trying to use a temporary memory stream to save the bitmap to and then copy to the zipStream, everything appears to work but the outcome is: it creates the zip file with the image file inside of it but the image file is empty.  I tried manually flushing the temp MemoryStream and then zipStream but that didn't do anything either.  I at least feel I am on the write track now, so Thanks!.

Comment: 5 minute after posting this I got it working, I just forgot to Seek back to the beginning of the tmpSteam after calling bmp.Save() on it. Thanks, guess I had the answer all along, but it felt like I was using to many streams.